# Dynamic view dimensions for different Devices

Tags: android, view, android-view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write app for multiple screen resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307009/how-to-write-app-for-multiple-screen-resolutions)

My Question is Suppose application has to  rendered views dynamically for different devices say for example

1.Frame to display images (eg 90 X 90 for mdpi 140 X 140 for hdpi)
  2.ListView Height (eg 120X 120 for mdpi 150 X 150 for hdpi)

Like if i have many things to set according to device size

What is the standard way to implement this instead of hard coding values in respective activities?
 Before loading application i want to calculate all dynamic view dimensions

Thanks in advance. Any Sample code really helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

use images in `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-hdpi`

for different height set use dimension in `values`

```
res/values-mdpi/dimen.xml
res/values-hdpi/dimen.xml
```

`dp, dip` will change according to the density.

use `px` in different dimension

Comment: thanks for reply.But i'm not asking about static images,Asking about views which hold data like grid view which holds number of images has to be different height and width used in different devices suppose if i use grid view of height 120dp in mdpi device say (320 X 480 ) 25 % of device height the same height can't be used for hdpi device means for different devices different height has to be set for that view .